# Traversing JSON objects with tSQL - OPENJSON

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, t-sql

I have the following JSON code. I pull the values into a SQL database using OPENJSON, but I am having trouble with the path for the Refund object.

I am trying to pull the "amount" value in the "transactions" object (so the expected value should be 298.47).

SQL code (currently returns only null values)

```
OPEN(json)
WITH( 
     OtherJSONstuff   varchar   '$otherjsonstuff'
     Refund           int       '$.refund[0].transactions.amount'  <what should this be
```

JSON Code

```
"otherjsonstuff": othervalues
"otherjsonstuff": othervalues
"object": [
    {
      "id": 212,
    "items": [
        {
          "id": 151,
          "quantity": 3,
          "item_id": 926,
          "subtotal": 30.0,
          "tax": 0.0,
          "item": {
            "id": 926,
            "quantity": 3,
            "price": "10.00",
            "product_id": 934,
            "properties": [],
            "discount": "0.00",
            "tax": []
          }
        }
      ],
      "action": [
        {
          "id": 537,
          "amount": "298.47", --this is the line I need
          "kind": "refund",
          "created": "2016-12-13",
          "location_id": null,
          "parent_id": 537,
        }
      ],
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Can you please add more info,like expected result and actual result.Also please add your SQLserver version

Comment: Done, and I honestly don't know the SQLServer version. Whatever the newest version is. I don't think it will make a big difference though.

Comment: Since `transactions` is also an array, you'll have to specify which `transaction` you want in your `refund` array. Perhaps your path should be `$.refund[0].transactions[0].amount`

Comment: You may find [this site](http://jsonpath.com/?) useful. You can toss your json in there and construct your path at the top and it will spit out the values it finds at that path. You just have to use a colon in front of your array ordinal there like `$.refund[:0].transactions[:0].amount` but other than that it's the same path syntax.

Comment: thank you sir, that worked perfectly

Comment: your sql version is `select @@version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having reformatted the JSON code,

it should be $.refund[0].transactions[0].amount

Depend on the array object you want to access, just increment and decrements the values. The root cause is understanding the JSON hierarchy and JNevil has provided you some good resources